# How to handle vendor prefixing for event handlers in Scala.js?

Tags: event-handling, scala.js, dom-events

The package `org.scalajs.dom.experimental` contains a facade for [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Prefixing). The current implementations seem to be vendor prefixed, at least for Chrome and Firefox. How can I use this facade to work with a vendor prefixed browser?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to polyfill the API with its spec'ed name, redirecting to the vendor-prefixed versions. For example, in a JavaScript file:

```
if (!Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty("fullscreenEnabled")) {
  if (Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty("webkitFullscreenEnabled"))
    Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, "fullscreenEnabled", {
      get: function() { return this.webkitFullscreenEnabled; }
    }
  }
}
```

or, in Scala.js:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.DynamicImplicits._
import js.Dynamic.{global => g}

if (!g.Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty("fullscreenEnabled")) {
  if (g.Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty("webkitFullscreenEnabled"))
    js.Object.defineProperty(g.Document.prototype, "fullscreenEnabled", js.Dynamic.literal(
        get = { (thiz: js.Dynamic) => thiz.webkitFullscreenEnabled; }: js.ThisFunction
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to polyfill event handlers as well? How can I make handlers registered to `onfullscreenerror` to be triggered on `onwebkitfullscreenerror`?

Comment: Hum, no idea. You would have better luck for that one in the Web community at large.